# ArcGIS JavaScript API Search widget doesn't work

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, search

I am a beginner of ArcGIS JavaScript API. I am creating a simple web map now. For some reason, the search widget of the map doesn't work. When I go to the console, it shows this error:
[image]

Here is my source code:

```js
var navigation;
var mainMap;
require([
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/Color",
    "esri/map",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "esri/dijit/Popup",
    "esri/InfoTemplate",
    "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
    "esri/dijit/Search",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/toolbars/navigation",
    "esri/dijit/Legend",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Color, Map, domConstruct, Popup, InfoTemplate,
            ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, Search, FeatureLayer, Navigation, Legend ){
    var fill = new SimpleFillSymbol("solid", null, new Color("#A4CE67"));
    var popup = new Popup({
        fillSymbol: fill
    },domConstruct.create("div"));

    mainMap = new Map("mainMap",{
        center: [-112,34.3],
        zoom: 7,
        basemap: "streets",
        infoWindow: popup
    });
    popup.startup();
    var providerInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
    providerInfoTemplate.setTitle("<b>Provider Information</b>");
    providerInfoTemplate.setContent("<b>Provider Name:</b><br> ${Provider} <br> <b>Address:</b><br> ${FullAddress} <br> <b>Type:</b><br> ${Type_Behavior_Health_Hospital_Health_Center_} <br> <b>Intergration Model:</b><br> ${IntergrationModel} <br>");
    var communityInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
    communityInfoTemplate.setTitle("<b>community Information</b>")
    communityInfoTemplate.setContent("Community Name: ${COUMMUNITY} <br>")
    var mainLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://arcgis-cabhp-1819518128.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/HCIC/160411_interactive_map_jzz_v01/MapServer",{});
    mainLayer.setInfoTemplates({
        0:{infoTemplate: providerInfoTemplate},
        7:{infoTemplate: communityInfoTemplate}
    });
    var mainSearch = new Search({
        enableButtonMode: false,
        enableLabel: false,
        enableInfoWindow: true,
        showInfoWindowOnSelect: false,
        map: mainMap
    }, "searchBar");
    var prividerLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://arcgis-cabhp-1819518128.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/HCIC/160411_interactive_map_jzz_v01/MapServer/0");
    var sources = mainSearch.get("sources");
    sources.push({
        featureLayer: prividerLayer,
        searchFields:["Provider"],
        displayField: "Provider",
        exactMatch: false,
        outFields:["Provider"],
        name: "HCIC Provider Information",
        maxResults: 6,
        maxSuggestions: 6,
        infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Provider Information", "Provider Nmae: ${Provider}</br>Provider Address: ${FullAddress}</br>Provider Type: ${Type_Behavior_Health_Hospital_Health_Center_}"),
        enableSuggestions: true,
        minCharacters: 0
    });
    mainSearch.set("sources", sources);
    mainSearch.startup();

    navigation = new Navigation(mainMap);
    myLegend = new Legend({
        map:mainMap,
        layerInfos:[{
            title:"Legend",
            layer:mainLayer,
            hideLayers:[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]
        }]
    }, "legendDiv");
    myLegend.startup();
    mainMap.addLayer(mainLayer);
});

function zoomToPrev(){
    navigation.zoomToPrevExtent();
}
function zoomToNext(){
    navigation.zoomToNextExtent();
}
function zoomToFull(){
    mainMap.setExtent(new esri.geometry.Extent(-116.5,30.8,-107.2,37.9));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error : `can't read property 'toJson' of null` , exactely here means that the widget tries to convert the geometry to a json object and he cant resolve this field (geometry).

In your featureLayer search refered to the url service : `http://arcgis-cabhp-1819518128.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services/HCIC/160411_interactive_map_jzz_v01/MapServer/0`
it seems that you have some thing wrong with the `Shape` field :

[image: shape fieald invisible]

So i think , you have  first to make your Shape field visible in the service then the search may work after .

Link may help you : [how to make shape visible in map service](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/00123-shape-field-is-not-visible.htm)

Comment: Agree! Probably it's because I turned that field off when I published the service. I will try to republish it and see if it works! Thank you buddy!

Comment: Hope it resolve your problem @DevilShankou